# Recuperar grupos de uma expressao regular em Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Estou executando esta expressão regular para separar os dígitos de uma versão:

```
([\d]+)+
```

Como podem ver neste [exemplo](http://regexr.com/3au7b), ela funciona suficientemente bem para cobrir minha necessidades.

Porém, tenho que adicionar este tratamento num script Perl, que não é de longe minha especialidade. Eu executo a minha regex e depois tento recuperar os valores do grupo.

```
$version="2.2.1-ALPHA30";
$version=~/([\d]+)+/g;
print "major:$1 minor:$2 revision:$3 build:$4\n"
```

Primeiro que só tenho `$1` que é mostrado, os outros ficam vazios.

E finalmente, não vejo maneira de saber quantos valores foram encontrados pela regex.

Comment: [Atualizei a resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/61109/6454), não vi que você precisava saber também a quantidade de números encontrados.

Comment: Preciso da quantidade para poder tratar mais a frente e gerenciar os casos degradados

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na expressão `([\d]+)+` não é necessário o colchete, nem o segundo operador de adição. Se você precisar colocas os resultados num *array* para contar a quantidade de ocorrências encontradas, faça:

```pl
$version="2.2.1-ALPHA30";
my @numeros = $version =~ /(\d+)/g;
$quantidade = scalar(@numeros);

print "Foram encontrados $quantidade números!\n";
print join(", ", @numeros);
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/Kz4k9I)</kbd>

Se você precisar saber o número de ocorrências e precisar trabalhar individualmente com cada uma, atribua a cada variável uma captura:

```pl
$version="2.2.1-ALPHA30";;
my $quantidade = () = my ($major, $minor, $revision, $build) = $version =~ /(\d+)/g;

print "Foi encontrado $quantidade resultados!\n";
print "$major, $minor, $revision, $build\n";
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/FazdjL)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

As respostas anteriores já dizem tudo...
Uma coisa que eu gosto no Perl é que as expressões regulares casam bem com as estruturas de controlo: **capturas e estruturas de controlo**

Os grupos de captura produzem listas quando usadas em contexto lista (como dito anteriormente)

```
@r = $version =~ m/(\d+)/g;
```

e devolvem o Verdadeiro/Falso em contexto booleano. Estas conversões implicitas
podem ser usados em diversas estruturas de controlo (untested):
 (1) `if`

```
$p = "stardict_3.0.4-1"
if($p =~ m/(.*?)_(\d+[.\d-]*)/ ) {  
    print "base=$1   version=$2 }
```

(2) `for`

```
$t="era uma vez um gato maltez";
for($t =~ m/(\w+)/g) { 
    $ocorrencia{$_}++ }
```

(3)`while`

```
$ls=`ls`;
while($ls =~ m/(\S+?)\.(\w+)/g ){ 
   print "nome=$1; extensao:$2\n"}
```

(4)`s/expressãoregular/ perl /e`

```
$text= "volto amanha";
$text =~ s/amanha/ `date --date="tomorrow"` /ge
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta assim:

```
$version="2.2.1-ALPHA30";
my @resultados = $version=~/([\d]+)+/g;
print join(", ", @resultados);
```

Usei o print apenas para mostrar todos os resultados que foram capturados. Podes usar o array para aceder a cada um dos resultados.

Caso apenas queiras o número podes usar o array como escalar.

Comment: Boa! Tendo o array eu consigo o `scalar(@resultados)` para ter a quantidade de números encontrados.